# Can sudoers on a server use my ssh keys if I generate them with a password?

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, sudoers

If I set up ssh keys for ssh login (to GitHub for example) from a server that I have access to, can sudoers on that server use my ssh keys if I generate them with a password (assuming they cannot crack the password)?

Answer (score 1):

Nope, that's exactly why SSH keys can be protected by a password, because the OS level protections aren't enough.  You must have the key's passphrase in order to use it.